# Databricks authentication to S3 Buckets failing

Tags: amazon-s3, databricks

Security problems connecting to S3 bucket in Data bricks

NB on databricks my account is still in trial period.  I've been using AWS for only a few months

I signed up with DB and used the built in tools for the cloud formation on my AWS account.

I have a Datalake on S3 that is loaded using lambda and Glue from an external POS system.  The files are all Json.

In my first (and only) workspace and started the compute cluster.

I opened a new python notebook and issues this very simple command to test the S3 connection:

Python command

```
dbutils.fs.ls("s3://hidden-bucket-name")
```

Error String:

java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3://hidden-bucket-name: getFileStatus on s3://hidden-bucket-name: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied; request: GET https://hidden-bucket-name.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com  {key=[], key=[false], key=[2], key=[2], key=[/]} Hadoop 3.3.4, aws-sdk-java/1.12.390 Linux/5.15.0-1040-aws OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.372-b07 java/1.8.0_372 scala/2.12.15 kotlin/1.6.0 vendor/Azul_Systems,_Inc. cfg/retry-mode/legacy com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Request; Request ID: VAMK134SSX7FM3VA, Extended Request ID: l/PmddVkv7otkOZnhZgeSc2HU9yiKej9ZsJ96xq3gQ+b5uQKDbw8QknQD8zJETYJM78V6jd5K74=, Cloud Provider: AWS, Instance ID: i-0feca026b7707fb3b credentials-provider: com.amazonaws.auth.AnonymousAWSCredentials credential-header: no-credential-header signature-present: false (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: VAMK134SSX7FM3VA; S3 Extended Request ID: l/PmddVkv7otkOZnhZgeSc2HU9yiKej9ZsJ96xq3gQ+b5uQKDbw8QknQD8zJETYJM78V6jd5K74=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: l/PmddVkv7otkOZnhZgeSc2HU9yiKej9ZsJ96xq3gQ+b5uQKDbw8QknQD8zJETYJM78V6jd5K74=:AccessDenied

Resolutions tried:
https://docs.databricks.com/en/aws/iam/instance-profile-tutorial.html#iam-step-7

Cause
Below are the common causes:

- AWS keys are used in addition to the IAM role. Using global init scripts to set the AWS keys can cause this behavior.

comment: I do have AWS Keys provisioned for local spark execution against remote s3 buckets.  I can’t imagine that this should impact an instance of spark running in a data bricks notebook

- The IAM role has the required permission to access the S3 data, but AWS keys are set in the Spark configuration. For example, setting spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key can conflict with the IAM role.

comment: See above, I do have this configuration for local spark execution.

- Setting AWS keys at environment level on the driver node from an interactive cluster through a notebook.

comment: Not sure what this means.

- DBFS mount points were created earlier with AWS keys and now trying to access using an IAM role.

comment: Not applicable.

- The files are written outside Databricks, and the bucket owner does not have read permission (see Step 7: Update cross-account S3 object ACLs).

https://docs.databricks.com/en/aws/iam/instance-profile-tutorial.html

comment: The Files contained in the bucket were written outside Databricks, but the I followed the steps above.  As a side note, there is no “Step 7” in the procedure above.

- The IAM role is not attached to the cluster.

Not sure how to attach an IAM role to the data bricks cluster … there is an instance profile attached to the workspace though

- The IAM role with read permission was attached, but you are trying to perform a write operation. That is, the IAM role does not have adequate permission for the operation you are trying to perform.

Comment: Not applicable

Solution
Below are the recommendations and best practices to avoid this issue:

- Use IAM roles instead of AWS keys.

Done.

- If you are trying to switch the configuration from AWS keys to IAM roles, unmount the DBFS mount points for S3 buckets created using AWS keys and remount using the IAM role.

Comment:  Not applicable.

- Avoid using global init script to set AWS keys. Always use a cluster-scoped init script if required.

Comment:  Not applicable not using global init script in data bricks

- Avoid setting AWS keys in a notebook or cluster Spark configuration.

Comment:  I do have AWS keys provisioned buy only used when running spark locally

I also ran through these articles:

https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/security/forbidden-access-to-s3-data

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/troubleshoot-403-errors.html

Comment: I discovered one work-around.  Set the data cluster's (compute) Access mode to either "Shared" or "Single User".  Both these settings work fine.  When the Access mode is "No Isolation Shared" then I get the permission problems.   Doing more research...

Answer (score 0):

We were also having similar issues. Here is what I did and it worked for me. We used it through EKS Container.

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider")
```

spark.read.format("delta").load("s3a:///")